# Programmatically schedule script execution with launchd or crontab

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, cron, launchd

I know how to create a configuration to schedule eg. a daily execution of a script with launchd or crontab on MacOS. However, I run into a scenario where I need to schedule the one-time execution of a script as part of a(nother) ruby script.

The hacky solution to that would be to manually write a `plist` file, and then running `launchctl load`, however that requires sudo privileges.

**Is there a better way of programmatically scheduling the one-time execution of a script in MacOS?**

Comment: If your script is web-based, you could use a 3rd-party service, such as [crono](https://www.crono.com/), to programmatically set up your jobs.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the at command.  I haven't  used it on mac os, but I would bet you can do `brew install at`  then you can run the at command to schedule a job `at` a specific time.

```
echo script.sh | at tomorrow noon
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Comment: This works, and `at` comes with MacOS - thanks for pointing this out. It's disabled by default, and can be disabled bu running `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist` (as specified by `man atrun`)

Comment: Thanks @ManuelEbert